# Inserting node into BST (C)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert a node into a bst, and I have the following so far

```
typedef struct _StoreNode *Connect;

typedef struct  _StoreNode {
   NumberFrequency  data;
   Connect   left;
   Connect   right;
} StoreNode;

Struct _StoreRep{
   Connect tree;
};

static Connect newConnect(char *w) {
   Connect n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
   n->data.frequency = 1;
   n->data.number = (char *)malloc(strlen(w) * sizeof(char));
   strcpy(n->data.number, w);
   n->left = NULL;
   n->right = NULL;
   return n;
}

NumberFrequency * insert(Connect n, char *w)
{
    if (n == NULL)
      return &newConnect(w)->data;
    else if (strcmp(n->data.number,w) > 0)
      return insert(n->left, w);
    else if (strcmp(n->data.number,w) < 0)
      return insert(n->right, w);
    else
       n->data.frequency = n->data.frequency+1;
    
   return &n->data;
}

NumberFrequency *DictInsert(Dict d, char *w){
   return insert(d->tree, w);
}
```

I am trying to return a pointer to the item that is being added into the BST. There are no errors thrown but nothing happens. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are not connecting the new node with the previous node. You are just creating a node but not connecting it to the root node.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually change the connections for the internal (non-leaf) nodes. Here's the updated function (I haven't tested it for syntax errors, but you should get the gist):

```c
NumberFrequency * insert(Connect n, char *w)
{
    if (n == NULL)
      return &newConnect(w)->data;
    else if (strcmp(n->data.number,w) > 0)
      n->left = insert(n->left, w);
    else if (strcmp(n->data.number,w) < 0)
      n->right = insert(n->right, w);
    else
       n->data.frequency = n->data.frequency+1;
    
   return &n->data;
}
```

Comment: This won't work as is - the recursive call does not return the new node as its result.

Comment: I get an error about incompatible pointer type on the lines n->left = insert(n->left, w); and n->right = insert(n->right, w);

Answer (score 0):

Try this for insert function

```c
if (n == NULL)
      return &newConnect(w)->data;

else {
        Connect *temp_ = n, *temp = NULL;
        while (temp_ != NULL) {
            if (strcmp(temp_->data.number, w) > 0) {
                temp = temp_;
                temp_ = temp_->r;
            }

            else if (strcmp(temp_->data.number, w) < 0) {
                temp = temp_;
                temp_ = temp_->l;           
            }
        }

        if (strcmp(temp->data.number, w) > 0) {
              temp->r = newConnect(w);
              return &temp->r->data;
        }

        else if (strcmp(temp_->data.number, w) < 0) {
              temp->l = newConnect(w);
              return &temp->r->data;          
        }
    }

n->data.frequency = n->data.frequency+1;

return &n->data;
```